# ORDER BY a specific row first, then the rest

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table where i'd like to have one specific row be the first row returned in the set, and then the rest of the rows in the table can follow.

I tried using a UNION to do this but it acted like i just did a regular select *

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
ORDER BY CASE 
    WHEN somecolumn = somevalue -- whatever identifies that row
THEN 1 ELSE 2 END
```